# Svcutil.exe MSBuild Task

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, svcutil.exe

Is there a task in MSBuild to execute svcutil.exe?  Or is there a definitive wrapper task somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching extensively, there does not appear to be a task either included or available to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) and run what ever you want.

Comment: Obviously, this is what I'll have to do if there is not a "definitive wrapper task somewhere."

Comment: You said "*Or* is there a definitive wrapper task", if your looking for "definitive wrapper task" only then don't start by asking "is there a task in MSBuild to execute svcutil.exe".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an MSBuild task for svcutil.exe.

Such a task may exist in [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) or the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack) though.